# Serving images from amazon s3 rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, paperclip

I am storing all the images in amazon S3 at the client side i don't want to show the amazon s3 urls for that i wrote attachments_controller with the following method

```
 def show
     send_data(
        open( @attachment.content.url, "rb").read, 
         :type => @attachment.content_content_type,
          :filename => @attachment.content_file_name,
          :disposition => "inline"
       )
 end
```

in the routes i added that every attachment needs to call the above action now everything is fine  but the problem is everytime it is rendering it is not caching it. Please let me know how to cache it better is action cache is the appropriate way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an answer to your questions posed in @Simone's answer.

You achieve this (with some effort) using [Amazon's Cloudfront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) cdn.

You can link multiple distributions to a single S3 bucket, and each distribution can have up to 10 CNAME's associated with it.

> **Multiple CNAME Aliases**
>
> You can use more than one CNAME alias
>   with a distribution. For example, you
>   could have alias1.example.com and
>   alias2.example.com both associated
>   with your distribution's domain name.
>   You can have up to 10 CNAME aliases
>   per distribution. You can associate a
>   particular CNAME alias with only one
>   distribution.

More info is available in the [developer guide.](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/)

Comment: @user315252 - you don't need to. You can have **multiple distributions per bucket** with 10 CNAMES per distribution so there is no limit.

Comment: one more problem with the approach is it won't provide the expiry url it will give the permanent link

Comment: @user315252 - Do you want private urls? You can use them: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/index.html?PrivateContent.html.

Comment: when you are using signed url again the host name would be same as s3.amazon..... which defeats the purpose of using CNAME

Comment: I am speaking about the method url_for which is used to get url which expires in certain amount of time

Comment: @user315252 - I can't find anything on Amazon that says you can't use CNAMES with private urls. But I did find a lot of blogs describing how to create private urls with cnames. Heres one example(see the bottom of page): http://support.rightscale.com/12-Guides/Dashboard_Users_Guide/Clouds/AWS_Global/CF_Origin_Access_Identities/Actions/Serving_Private_Content

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you map a custom DNS name to the amazon bucket, and let amazon serve the assets for you?

References:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/172941/cname-record-for-amazon-s3-any-drawbacks
- http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/using-amazon-s3-as-an-image-hosting-service.html

Comment: Cool! Didn't know that was possible. That would be a CNAME record pointing to the bucket domain, right?

Comment: Exactly. I added a couple of references in the answer. There are also some details in the official Amazon S3 documentation.

Comment: my app will be of per customer basis it is like customername.myapp.com and the customername will change per customer .. i want to show to the customer like that he is getting images from  customername.myapp.com will that be possible in paperclip

Comment: @user315252 - you can only map 1 custom domain to your bucket so its not possible to do what you want. Unless you proxy the downloads through your server but that somewhat defeats the object of using S3

Comment: how to actually create a proxy to the amazon s3 without hitting muliple requests ?

Comment: @user315252 - you don't want to do that. It would work something like: the clients hits a url on your server, the server fetches the actual file from S3 and then returns it to the client. Don't do it.

Comment: then how to solve the problem of not displaying the s3 url and not hitting to many request by reading it everytime